# Confused with AT&T assembly syntax

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86

Are these two instructions performing the same operation:

```
mov $0x80000000, %esp
mov $0x80000000, (%esp)
mov $0x80000000, 0(%esp)
```

Also, what does this instruction do:

```
mov (%eax), %eax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st: `esp` = 0x80000000

2nd and 3rd: 4 bytes of memory at address from `esp` = 0x80000000.

Last: `eax` = 4 bytes of memory at address from `eax`.

Btw, the `l` suffix is probably missing. I usually see these instructions as `movl`, meaning move a *long* value (=4 bytes).

Find a (g)as or AT&T assembly syntax tutorial. You're not the first to ask this kind of question.

Comment: Thank you. But next time just answer the question.